# Encode strings parsed by HXT to proper UTF8 String

Tags: haskell, utf-8, hxt

I am parsing utf8-encoded pages using hxt, simplified parser example:

```
names = multi (hasName "h1") >>> proc h1 do
  name <- getText <<< getChildren -< h1
  returnA name
```

Everything goes normal until I try to print names:

```
*Main > n
"\208\152\208\182\208\190\209\128\208\176-\208\161"
*Main > :t n
n :: String
*Main > putStrLn n
ÐÐ¶Ð¾ÑÐ°-Ð¡
*Main > Data.Text.IO.putStrLn $ Data.Text.pack n
ÐÐ¶Ð¾ÑÐ°-Ð¡
```

I am parsing using option `withInputEncoding "utf8"`.
How is it possible to properly encode string parsed by hxt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `decodeUtf8` from `Data.Text.Encoding` in combination with `pack` from `Data.ByteString.Char8.pack`:

```
*Main > import Data.Text.Encoding as E
*Main > import Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
*Main > import Data.Text.IO as T

*Main > T.putStrLn . E.decodeUtf8 . C.pack $ n

Ижора-С
```